# What does the look ahead in Regex do?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help deciphering Regex

```
(\*\*|__)(?=\S)([^\r]*?\S[*_]*)\1
```

This came from [showdown.js](https://github.com/remy/showdown/blob/master/src/showdown.js)

```
(\*\*|__)          match ** or __
(?=\S)             -> look ahead for *one* non-space character? what for? 
([^\r]*?\S[*_]*)   -> zero or more non-carriage-returns, why newlines \n allowed?, one non-space, zero or more * or _ characters
\1                 ends with 1st capture: ** or __
```

I mainly don't get the 2nd & 3rd lines

Comment: Why don’t you ask the author?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a stab at the second part (keep in mind I guess based on the knowledge that this is a JS Markdown parser):

The lookahead assertion `(?=\S)` is probably there in case someone wants to write two asterisks ** or two underscores __ without wanting to bold the text that comes after it *that is separated by a space* (see what I did there?).

```
** This text will not be bold. **
**This text will be bold.**
```

> ** This text will not be bold. **
>   **This text will be bold.**

Comment: I have no clue about why the third part excludes `\r` but not `\n` though, sorry.